# Save ServerValue.TIMESTAMP as string in realtime database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

I'm trying to save the firebase timestamp as a string, I'm using realtime database, I want to arrange my nodes based on their post date and I want to exclude those posts that are older than 24 h. 
my node structure is something like this

```
 "posts" : {
      "b" : {
        "text" : "5",
        "timestamp" : "{.sv=timestamp}",
         "uid" : "KpZvp0bhOlPJI3KKwe1AF7Apb2U2"
      },
      "a" : {
        "text" : "hey",
        "timestamp" : "1559912589250",
        "uid" : "KpZvp0bhOlPJI3KKwe1AF7Apb2U2"
      }
 }
```

I have no problem arranging the posts based on the date but when I want to exclude the posts that are older than 24 h that's when I start having trouble

```
  firebaseDatabase.reference.child("posts").orderByChild("timestamp").startAt((System.currentTimeMillis() - 86400000))
```

the "startAt()" doesn't take long or integers it only takes boolean, strings and double as parameters.

this is how I create the nodes

```
    firebaseDatabase.reference.child("posts").push().setValue(mapOf(
            "by" to uid,
            "text" to "hey",
            "timestamp" to  ServerValue.TIMESTAMP)
    )
```

I tried changing the ServerValue.TIMESTAMP to string but it saves it as "{".sv" : "timestamp"}" I looked around and I found out that if I send a map with an index that is named ".sv" and has the value of "timestamp" so that the database will recognize it and replace the value with the server timestamp 
something like this

```
                firebaseDatabase.reference.child("posts").push().setValue(mapOf(
            "by" to uid,
            "text" to "hello",
            "timestamp" to mapOf(".sv" to "timestamp")
```

the timestamp value will be the server timestamp as a long number, so basically the ServerValue.TIMESTAMP is like a map, that's why when I tried changing it to a string it gave me "{".sv" : "timestamp"}" value.

So how can I save the server timestamp as a string? or how can I query the data as a Long number without changing it to string

Comment: You should store the timestamp as a number, which is what `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` does. The `{".sv" : "timestamp"}` is just a marker that the Firebase servers replace with the server-side timestamp as a number. Can you edit your question to show the actual JSON (as text, no screenshot)? You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Yes, It is saving it as a number now, but as I said I can't exclude the old posts if the time stamp is a number it has to be either a string, boolean, or double.

Comment: *"the "startAt()" doesn't take long or integers it only takes boolean, strings and double as parameters."*. You can pass an integer, and it will get converted to a double automatically.  It will still work the way you expect when it actually compares values.

Comment: It can't take integer, kotlin will give me the folloing error "

None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.
startAt(Boolean) defined in com.google.firebase.database.Query
startAt(Double) defined in com.google.firebase.database.Query
startAt(String?) defined in com.google.firebase.database.Query
"

Comment: I'm with Doug here: what's the problem that you have on this line `firebaseDatabase.reference.child("posts").orderByChild("timestamp").startAt((System.currentTimeMillis() - 86400000))`? Not in your words, but what does the compiler say? If it doesn't compile because the value is not a double and isn't auto-converted, multiply it by `1.0` to convert it?

Comment: multiply it by 1.0 work somehow, please put it as an answer so I can mark it